# How to handle navigation with dynamic views iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview

I am adding custom UIViews to my UIScrollView, and every UIView has a button that needs to open some users profile which must open in new UIViewController. But how do i create and connect a new controller with that button?

Here is my code:

```
class FollowersViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    for  var i = 0; i < count; i++ {

        view = FollowerView(frame: CGRectMake(0, scrollHeight, self.view.frame.width, 62))

        scrollView.addSubview(view)
        scrollHeight += view.frame.height
        scrollView.contentSize.height += view.frame.height
    }



}
```

If there is a button inside my CustomView that opens different (maybe dynamic) ViewControllers depending on its content how can I handle this issue?

Comment: Can you show your FollowerView implementation?

Comment: I can but it makes no sense, it works correctly, but i dont know how to handle event on let `followGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "follow:")
        follow.addGestureRecognizer(followGesture)` to open new window(ViewController)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `button` to your `view`, and assign a tag to it. Based on this tag, you can check which button is calling the selector `actionForButton` using a switch-case:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    for  var i = 0; i < count; i++ {
        var view: CustomView = followers[i]
        view = FollowerView(frame: CGRectMake(0, scrollHeight, self.view.frame.width, 62))

        var button = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40))        
        button.addTarget(self, action: "actionForButton", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        button.tag = i;
        view.addSubview(button)

        scrollView.addSubview(view)
        scrollHeight += view.frame.height
        scrollView.contentSize.height += view.frame.height
    }
}


func actionForButton(sender: UIButton) {

    switch (sender.tag)
    {

    case 0: //perform related task
        break

    case 1: //perform related task
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: Its nice try, but if dynamically create views i dont know their amount and cant create switch states for all view.

Comment: but its nice if i can use tag as argument for some function like: `func actionForButton(sender: UIButton) { opneVievController(sender.tag) }` can i do so?

Comment: sure. assuming `opneVievController` is your func which uses the argument to open the respective view controller.

Comment: this worked for me, but for this purpose delegates may be the proper use.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to modify your CustomView to accept 1 parameter as UIViewController. And then when your are adding gesture set this controller as target.

Code:

```
view = FollowerView(self, frame: CGRectMake(0, scrollHeight, self.view.frame.width, 62))
```

Your CustomView init:

```
func init(controller: UIViewController, frame: CGRect)
```

And your view gestureRecognizer:

```
followGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: controller, action: "follow:") 
follow.addGestureRecognizer(followGesture)
```

Then in your FollowersViewController you can implement your target function:

```
func follow(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    // do your stuff
}
```

Comment: Than you, i think this can work as i need, so i do so... is it good purpose for doing this or it can make problems?

Comment: I can't answer your question because i'm a newbie in iOS). Maybe some one can explain the danger of doing this but I can't, sorry). I use this when it is needed and it works..